# How can I generate a video with a single solid color that changes at intervals with FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg

For testing purposes, I want to generate a video that changes between a solid black and a solid white color every frame at 10 fps, how can I do this using FFMPEG?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Even if you've just looked up tutorials or examples, and couldn't find any, please [edit] your question and include what you've looked for.

Comment: Rather than a video file, could you use an app such as *IsMyLcdOK*, https://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Microsoft/IsMyLcdOK ?

Answer (score 0):

The glib answer is "spend 3 hours studying how ffmpeg filters work" - what I've done today for fun, so I used this question as a challenge.

Looks like there's a number of ways to get the result but here's what worked for me:

1. Generate a black image and a white image, naming them `img-001.png` and `img-002.png`.
2. Use `ffmpeg`'s `-loop` function, which I learned from [this answer is just for image-to-video work](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/12906)

Generating images:

```bash
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=black:1920x1080:d=3,format=rgb24 -frames:v 1 -y img-001.png

ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=white:1920x1080:d=3,format=rgb24 -frames:v 1 -y img-002.png
```

Loop those images that for 30 seconds at 10 fps:

```bash
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i 'img-%03d.png' -r 10 -t 30 -vf format=yuv420p -y out.mp4
```

`ffprobe` reports this metadata:

```
(edited for clarity)
Duration: 00:00:30.00, start: 0.000000, 
Video: h264 (High) yuv420p
1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 20 kb/s, 10 fps
```

[This gist has another approach](https://gist.github.com/clungzta/bdcf76924db5835f8a00a636d0a0cdab) that uses `filter_complex`. Though it isn't doing exactly the same thing, it could be adapted for this task.